# Imagemagick not working in linux + ubuntu

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have installed imageMagick in ubuntu server i have installed imagemagick but i can not found it in info.php

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);


$src_img = new Imagick("images/insurance.jpg");
echo $src_img;

?>
```

it can not find Imagick class

Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found in /var/www/html/new_details.php on line 570

Comment: Have you installed the php-extension for image magic as well?

Comment: can you provide me link for that

Comment: Try: `sudo apt install php-imagick`. If you're using Apache with mod_php, you need to restart Apache after. If you're using Nginx with php-fpm, then you need to restart php-fpm after.

Comment: I have already installed it

Comment: Have you restarted the web server (or php-fpm, if that is used)?

Answer (score 2):

try to use

```
php -m | grep imagick
```

if result is null(empty) then run this command

```
sudo apt-get install php-imagick
```

and restart the apache2 server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: You can remove `php5-imagick` and just have `php-imagick`. You could also mention that you need to restart Apache (if the OP is using Apache with mod_php) or php-fpm (if the OP is using php-fpm).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks for suggestion  i edit the answer